# LWJGL Function is not supported?

Tags: java, image, lwjgl

**EDIT: Since people still land here from google, you MUST call every OpenGL methods in a OpenGL context. So be sure you are in a context before doing anything with GL.**

I am trying to render a simple text on my screen using lwjgl but everytime, it failed! When i launch the game, it crash and throw me that error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin(GL11.java:682)
at com.zarax.gui.GuiRenderer.renderString(GuiRenderer.java:63)
at com.zarax.main.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Did i need to use modern openGL things or what? I really need help here

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71578/why-do-i-get-function-not-supported-exceptions-for-opengl-3-2-functions-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Display.create()`:

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1080, 720));
Display.setTitle("Game");
Display.create(attribs);
```

Comment: i did :( Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);

Comment: Oh wait that's not the issue. Refer to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71578/why-do-i-get-function-not-supported-exceptions-for-opengl-3-2-functions-using

Particularly the comments on the answer

Answer (score 0):

I saw that glTexCoord2f and glVertex2f is no longer in the core of lwjgl, i must find another way to do that :x